# how to create fastest image from chart

Tags: java, swing, graph, charts, jfreechart

I am using JCChart to create charts, at the end I have to create image from this this chart. I apply following procedure.

```
frame.add(chart);
Image img=chart.createImage(600, 800);
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
g.setClip(0, 0, chart.getSize().width, chart.getSize().height+chart.getSize().height);
chart.paint(g);
```

In this procedure, when data for the chart is very large then line

```
 chart.paint(g)
```

takes very much time and also use much of heap memory, so can any body tell me another way so that I can create image in fast way.

Thanks & Regards
Dilip Agarwal

Comment: You could use `Robot.createScreenCapture` if chart is fully shown on screen, this would avoid lengthy rendering but this strategy has major flaws (if your frame is not on top, or the frame is not big enough to show the full chart, etc...).

Comment: @Guillaume Polet , actually Chart does not shows to the user at screen, but user just give request to create images of graph between selected range of date. and program automatically create the image and after that that image is shown to the user

Answer (score 1):

**Edited : Sorry, I thought you are using jfreechart.**

You can also use ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG() function of jfreechart library. It would save only chart area as...

ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File(graph_file_name), chart, 800, 600);

Answer (score 1):

If data become large then you will have to increase the heap size so that processing may do faster.
so use

```
 java -Xmx
```